# Convert string representation of matrix to matrix

Tags: string-manipulation, python

I have a Python script which generates and outputs Mathematica matrices. I use RunProcess to run my Python script and I extract the StandardOutput which is the Mathematica matrix as a string.

What I would like to do is take that string and perform matrix operations on it, for example, compute its eigenvectors.

For example:

```
RunProcess[{"python", "myscript.py"}][[2]]
```

which outputs

```
{{0, 0, 1-r, 0, 0, 1-r},{1-r, 1-r, 0, 1-r, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, r, 0, 0, r},{r, r, 0, r, 0, 0}}
```

and I would like to have something like

```
MyMatrix[r_] := RunProcess[{"python", "myscript.py"}][[2]]
```

Which would give me the equivalent of:

```
MyMatrix[r_] := {{0, 0, 1-r, 0, 0, 1-r},{1-r, 1-r, 0, 1-r, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
0},{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, r, 0, 0, r},{r, r, 0, r, 0, 0}}
```

which I can perform matrix operations on. The problem is, when I extract the standard out, the output is in a string format and it isn't converting to a symbolic matrix automatically. Is there some command I can use? Thanks.

Comment: Try `ToExpression` - also, side note, consider not using single-character uppercase symbol names like `M`.  You might be redefining system symbols!

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe I'm not using it correctly... I'll post the output of it in the question.

Comment: `ToExpression["{{1-r, 1-r, 0},{0, 0, 1},{r, r, 0}}"]` gives me a 3x3 matrix (you could test with `Dimensions`). You can call (for example) `Eigenvalues` on it and get `{1, 0, -r}`. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am expecting. I'll try again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah... I did something stupid.. I had already defined r as something. It works. Thanks a lot. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the function `ToExpression`.

```
ToExpression["{{1-r, 1-r, 0},{0, 0, 1},{r, r, 0}}"]
```

will transform the string `"{{1-r, 1-r, 0},{0, 0, 1},{r, r, 0}}"` into a 3x3 matrix.